# How to solve a $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}{x}$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

This is a home work problem. How to solve:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}
\frac{\sqrt{1-\cos2x}}{x}$$

If I plug $$x=0$$ in the equation I get $$\frac{0}{0}$$

Any ideas how to find this limit? Tips welcome. :)

I know you can take derivative when you've 0 over 0, but in this case it doesn't simplify it. Actually in this homework I can't take derivative and have to solve it somehow else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x,\sqrt{1-\cos2x}=\sqrt2|\sin x|$

Now for real $a, |a|=+a$ if $a\ge0$ else $|a|=-a$

So, $\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{|\sin x|}x=-\lim_{x\to0^-}\dfrac{\sin x}x=-1$ and you should complete the rest

Comment: The limit does not exists becuase if you approach $0$ from the right (Lab already did the one when $x$ approaches from the left, you will get $1$. Hence the limit of such a functions as $x$ approaches $0$ does not exist. I hope this helps. By the way, (+1) to Lab. Bye

Comment: @PedroArbizu, I left it for bodacydo :)

Comment: I solved it, the limit is $\sqrt(2)$ if x goes to $0$ from positive, and it's $-\sqrt(2)$ if x goes to $0$ from negative. :)

Comment: Oh wait... You say it doesn't exist...? Why?

Comment: Because limits from both sides have to be equal for limit to exist, yes?

Comment: But I can still have two one-sided limits, right? There is left sided limit, right sided limit and the one when both come together, correct?

Comment: If $$ \lim_{x \to \alpha^{+} } f(x) \neq \lim_{x \to \alpha^{-}} f(x) $$, then $\lim_{x \to \alpha } f(x) $ does not exist.

Comment: @PedroArbizu, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Existence_and_one-sided_limits